# Units in Plasma Physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plasma-physics, unit-conversion, absolute-units

What are the units people use in plasma physics? I am having hard time converting an equation from an old paper to SI units.

I saw temperature being defined in $eV$. I assume this is $eV/k_B$ with $k_B$ being 1 they do not mention it. Am I right?

Please let me know the units of

$k_B$

Temperature

Z* (ionization state)

Electric charge

mass

charge density

Comment: Read up on [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)

Comment: Thanks. I have. But the papers I am refering to seem to use J/cm^2 but then use temperature in eV. so I am all confused with regards to what things they change and what they do not

Comment: That's the thing. Do dimensional analysis. If the units correctly correspond to the quantity they are given to, then it's fine. If not, then use the natural constants to convert to proper units. If that doesn't end up working, it's their fault, not yours

Comment: The NRL plasma formulary is a compilation of formulas used by many people working in plasma physics, this should give you some ideas of the units etc: www.nrl.navy.mil/ppd/content/nrl-plasma-formulary

Comment: Temperatures are usually in eV.  There are ~11604 K per 1 eV, which is roughly the magnitude of the elementary charge to the Boltzmann constant, $k_{B}$.  The units of $k_{B}$ are J/K.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, for the general purposes of plasma physics, $k_b$ is defined in $eV/K$, or electron volts per kelvin.  You will sometimes see reference to the electron temperature being in units of $eV$ rather than $K$, but this is a simplified way of writing the temperature to deal with scales on the order of 10^4 $K$.  In other words, it is easier to say that a plasma has an electron temperature of 2 $eV$ rather than 23208 $K$, and because electrons already have an energy unit based on their mass and charge, this choice makes mathematical sense.

As far as other units:

$k_B [J/K]$ or $[eV/k]$

Temperature (electron/ion) $[eV]$

Temperature (neutral gas) $[K]$

Z* (ionization state) $[dimensionless]$

Electric charge $[elementary$ $charge]$, $1.60217662 × 10^{-19} C$

mass $[amu], [kg], or [g]$

charge density is often expressed in terms of inverse volume $[cm^{-3}]$ or $[m^{-3}]$ since the number of charged particles per unit volume is often of more interest than the total charge per unit volume.  This is the case for both electrons and ions.